# Azure Service Bus negative amount of scheduled messages

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to get a message from queue in some special time. So I use scheduled message in queue. I send messages via ScheduleMessageAsync method.

For getting messages I use Azure Web Job with ServiceBusTrigger.

I send a couple of messages, everything works fine on my side, but in Azure Portal, if I go to page with my queue I see that I have negative amount of messages in queue.

I had this problem some days ago, but then it disappeared, but now appears again.

Is it problem in my logic or just a bug in UI of Azure?

UPD: I had an unhandled exception in my web job, so, it seems like the problem was because of this.

But I still don't know why counter became less than 0

[image]

Comment: It's clearly a bug with message counts. You should raise an issue or open support case.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, also when I tried to get counts directly from my code I also got this negative value

Comment: that would even more point in the direction of a bug.

Comment: Late to the party and allegedly fixed: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/254 ... but I am encountering a -1 scheduled message count.