# Negative Value Azure ServiceBus Active Message Count

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Discovered a puzzling metric -- a negative value for the `Active Message Count`.  I've confirmed that both ServiceBus Explorer (v3.0.4) and the Azure Portal report the same negative value.

How can this happen?

I've the following settings enabled for my SB Queue:

- Enable Batch Operations
- Enable Dead Lettering On Message Expiration
- Enable Partitioning
- Enable Express
- Lock Duration:  `1 minute`

Is this something to be worried about?  Feels like this might be a bug in ServiceBus.

Comment: It's a bug with metrics I suspect. Suggest to raise an issue with Microsoft. And also update SBExplorer to version 4.x

Comment: Thanks for the tip on SB Explorer @SeanFeldman.  Got the latest and discovered some nice new features.  IMO there's some sort of SB service issue with the metrics here -- the Queues have definitely gone negative.  Maybe some integer overflow somewhere?

Comment: There is a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927398/azure-service-bus-negative-amount-of-scheduled-messages) too but related to scheduled message count

Comment: The portal is using a different API to retrieve message counts than the .NET client. Since both show negative counts, that's a broker side issue. I'll raise it with the team.

Answer (score 1):

Could you raise an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus) and share a repro of the code?